# Who IS Cait Sith?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In Final Fantasy VII it's revealed Cait Sith is actually

> a robot controlled by someone in Shinra Headquarters.

As you've been there before, is there any clue to whom it actually is at any point?

Comment: Reeve Tuesti . . . .
i bet he is a proffesional gamer if he can control that little robot against Sephiroth and win (in my playtrough)

Comment: The game reveals this later on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Final Fantasy VII Cait Sith is a cat, riding a giant stuffed toy moogle, working as a fortune-teller in the Gold Saucer. His true identity is that of Reeve Tuesti's who controls Cait Sith remotely like a puppet. Even though Reeve is Shinra Electric Power Company's head of Urban Development he ***is*** interested in saving the Planet.

[image: Cait Sith] **=** [image: Reeve Tuesti]

Reeve is an Architect who designed the Mako reactors. He supports the cancellation of the Space Program following the crash in Rocket Town. He later supports the Turks when they briefly split from Shinra by using his puppet, Cait Sith to aid them.

The character of Cait Sith actually appears in several other entries in the Final Fantasy series, usually as just a cat, sometimes as a summon other times as an enemy.

Source [Final Fantasy Wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cait_Sith_%28Final_Fantasy_VII%29)

Comment: Support the Avalanche you mean ?

Comment: funfact : you can play as Cait Sith in FF7 : Dirge of Cerberus , Stealth game style. . .

Comment: I find the phrasing a little weird. If I understand correctly, Cait Sith is the name of the cat. The cat is controlling a stuffed to moogle. But in reality the cat is a robot/something, who is remotely controlled by a human called Reeve Tuesti. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Colin: your link points to this question. I think it should be http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cait_Sith_%28Final_Fantasy_VII%29 :)

Comment: @Py. Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it now.

Comment: as per the implied part of the OP's question about if there were clues in the Headquarters, In the Gym's change room of the Shinra Headquaters there's a microphone hanging in one of the lockers which in your revisit during Diamond Weapon's attack on Midgar becomes a weapon for Cait Sith. I'm not sure where i remember reading it but this locker actually belongs to Reeve. ofcause by the time you get the microphone as a weapon you already know the connection between Reeve and Cait Sith

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly, there is a bit of dialogue where Barret identifies Cait Sith's true identity when he says something like

> You're caught Reeve.

I believe there are a few other hints dropped, but it has been a while since I played through FF7

Comment: I just played through it again a month or so ago, and although I already knew the answer ahead of time, I thought the game made it pretty dang explicit at the end of Disc 2.

Comment: @CloudyMusic I originally played it when it released, and haven't played since. Yesterday while playing he revealed himself as a spy but I couldn't recall 'who' he was. Hence why I thought I'd ask =)